# Making a sprite animation in QML

Tags: qt, animation, qml, sprite

I am trying to write a little program, which has to connect to the Internet. While doing this, the app should show an animation which I have made in Flash Professional and exported as a sprite sheet. 
[image]
I use the AnimatedSprite Type in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1

 ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
           | Qt.Window
    color:"#00000000"
    title:"Presenter Remote"

Rectangle{
    color:"steelblue"
    height:parent.height
    width:parent.width
    radius: 10
}

Image {
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.topMargin: -20
    scale: 0.5

    source: "close.png"
    MouseArea {
        width:parent.width
        height:parent.height
        onClicked: Qt.quit()
    }


}

AnimatedSprite{

source: "Animation_Cloud.png"
anchors.centerIn: parent
frameHeight:313
frameWidth:232
running: true
frameCount:60
frameDuration: 20
width:232
height:313


}


}
```

When I compile and launch I get the sprite animating, but it moves from right to left while doing it.
[image: Moving sprite]

How can I set the sprite still and just keep the "half arrows" moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your sprite sheet; remove the excess space from the right hand side of the .png.

Comment: It is still wobbling around, but it got less strong.I will try to optimate it in Photoshop.